# How can i import sklearn?

Tags: python, import

When trying to import sklearn i get the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8fd979e02004> in <module>()
----> 1 import sklearn

c:\python35-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>()
     55 else:
     56     from . import __check_build
---> 57     from .base import clone
     58     __check_build  # avoid flakes unused variable error
     59 

c:\python35-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in <module>()
      7 
      8 import numpy as np
----> 9 from scipy import sparse
     10 from .externals import six
     11 from .utils.fixes import signature

c:\python35-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\__init__.py in <module>()
    211 
    212 from .base import *
--> 213 from .csr import *
    214 from .csc import *
    215 from .lil import *

c:\python35-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csr.py in <module>()
     11 from scipy._lib.six import xrange
     12 
---> 13 from ._sparsetools import csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks, \
     14         get_csr_submatrix, csr_sample_values
     15 from .sputils import upcast, isintlike, IndexMixin, issequence, get_index_dtype

ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

Comment: How did you install SciKit Learn? I recommend using Anaconda (https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

Comment: Since the answer turned out to be "install it first" I'm voting to close as no longer reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using [Anaconda](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install) or pip / easy_install to install sklearn. You should also look up Docker, because it might save you tremendous amount of time later.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Anaconda fixed the problem for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

firstly make sure you have numpy and scipy , if present then make sure it is up to date.

to install numpy use cmd and type

```
pip install numpy
```

to install scipy

```
pip install scipy
```

if already present then upgrade it using

```
pip install -U numpy
pip install -U scipy
```

then close your idle and try to run your code again.